# Error when deploying Rails application to Fly.io - PG::undefinedtable: error: relation "trips" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment

My Rails application runs fine on my local machine, but whenever I deploy it to fly.io I get a PG error (Postgres) stating that my relations don't exist.

In deploy, whenever I try to open a view that contains some table This is the error log:

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "trips" does not exist`

This is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  username: jforno
  password: counterstrike123

development:
  <<: *default
  database: CargoMatch_development
  host: localhost`

test:
  <<: *default
  database: CargoMatch_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: CargoMatch_production
  username: CargoMatch
  password: <%= ENV["CARGOMATCH_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

A already tried to reinstall Postgresql, ran "rails db:reset" and tried with different database.yml configurations and nothing worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably something like this should work `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error you're encountering is related to your PostgreSQL database schema not being properly migrated or set up on the deployment environment. All you need to do is run:

```bash
bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

in your fly.io instance or via `flyctl`.